# OnClickListener of Button not working

Tags: android, button

I am just trying to initiliazing by variables by Buttons and variables.
But when i try to initialize the if I set my OnClickListeners for the buttons the applications gets stopped unexpectedly. 
If i comment the lines of setting the OnClickListener the application is working fine. So I am sure that the problem is definitely with the OnClickListener.I have also attached my activity in the AndroidManifest.XML
The class name is Data.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Data extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button start, startFor;
    EditText sendET;
    TextView gotAnswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initialise();
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        **startFor.setOnClickListener(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);**
    }

    private void initialise() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSA);
        startFor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSAFR);
        sen

    dET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSend);
            gotAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGot);


        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case (R.id.bSA):
                break;
            case (R.id.bSAFR):
                break;

            }

        }

    }
```

and the corresponding Manifest added activity is

```
<activity
            android:name=".Data"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

Whats the error in setting the OnClickListener... is their something wrong that I am doing ?

Comment: case (R.id.bSA): will this work? I will generlly use case R.id.bSA:

Comment: @Padma Kumar : does it makes any difference.. does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified a view for your activity. Just after you call `super.onCreate(..)`, call `setContentView(R.id.mylayoutid)`, where mylayoutid is the name of the xml layout which contains the buttons.

Comment: yes i tried.. but this still doens't work ... again the problem lies in the OnClickListener
this is the modified code ...

                initialise();
  setContentView(R.layout.get);
  start.setOnClickListener(this);
  startFor.setOnClickListener(this);

........ 
Just wanted to tell that I am using ECLIPSE and building for API level 7

Comment: swap the order of `initialise()` and `setContentView()`. You need to set the content view *before* you try to access the views (which you're doing in `initialise()`)

Comment: no problem. Don't forget to set the question as answered (the tick on the left)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your content view after your initialise method. You need to do it before you attempt to access your UI components.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);            

        initialise();
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Espiandev is right, `setContentView(R.id.mylayoutid)` must come right after the super call.

In addition, It might be easier for you to do this in your layout xml:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/bSA"
        ...
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/bSAFR"
        ...
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

You don't even have to implement View.OnClickListener this way, or call setOnClickListener - when the layout XML is inflated, the click listeners will be assigned automatically.